# how to replace text with image in html/css

Tags: html, css

I would like to replace text with image, but I want also to have the text on the web page, which is related to the image. This is because i would like the search machines to list the web page at the top, according to the text in the web page.

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you are describing the "sliding doors" technique.

HTML:

```
<div class="myImg">This is the text</div>
```

CSS:

```
.myImg {
    background:url(myImg.gif) 0 0 no-repeat;
    display:block;
    height:200px; /* your image height */
    text-indent:-99999em;
    width:200px; /* your image width */
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

alt tags on any images

Like this:

```
<img src="image.jpg" alt="This is an image">
```

in your image tags.

-- Simon

Answer (score 0):

your question is unclear of what is it that you really want. But here is what I think you are looking for.

```
<img src="img/SMS.jpg" width="200" height="150" alt="free SMS services" title="a page about SMS services" />
```

As you can see the title will display as you hover over the image (also helps with screen readers) and the alt will be picked up by search for SEO purposes. Then on you page you will have text that corresponds to the image.

Comment: Thanks Anele, but I'm not sure if only the alt attribute is enought for SEO purposes.