# Replace the text of a <li> with image

Tags: javascript, html, image, events, onclick

How can i replace the text of a `<li>` with an image when an event is called?
When the `<li>` is clicked i want to come an image at this place. I tried with `innerHTML` but no result.
Any idea?

```
<ul onclick="myFunction(event)">

 <li>1</li>
 <li>2</li>
 <li>3</li>

</ul>

function myFunction(event){
  var t;
  if(event.target){
    t = event.target;
  }else{
    t = event.srcElement;
  }

t.innerHTML = '<img src="img.png">';
}
```

Comment: What have you tried with `innerHTML`? Please show us your code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8138414

Comment: https://onelittledesigner.com/rapidweaver/rapidweaver-snippets/replacing-text-with-an-image-using-jquery/

Comment: Please show us your current code, and what the expected result is.

Comment: do you have tried anything so far, can you post the code

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a structure like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>Some Text</li>
</ul>
```

You can use the following script as an event listener function:

```
document.querySelector("li").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  let image = document.createElement("IMG");
  image.src = "//placehold.it/20"; // example image
  this.innerText = ""; // remove text
  this.append(image); // append image to the li
});
```

This code in action:

```js
document.querySelector("li").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  let image = document.createElement("IMG");
  image.src = "//placehold.it/20"; // example image
  this.innerText = ""; // remove text
  this.append(image); // append image to the li
});
```

```html
<ul><li>Some Text</li></ul>
```

Comment: I will replace my function with this one?

Comment: Now, in your code you are attaching the click listener to the `<ul>` instead of the `<li>`, so no, you would also need to remove the listener from the `<ul>`